# How to lock a vector in java so that just one thread can use it at the same time?

Tags: java, multithreading, swing

I have a vector which is shared between multiple threads and when I try to read from this vector using one of these threads, I got a StreamCorruptedException.

Here is the stacktrace of the exception:

`java.io.StreamCorruptedException: invalid stream header: 7371007E
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readStreamHeader(ObjectInputStream.java:801)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.<init>(ObjectInputStream.java:298)
    at prj.ReadThread.run(ReadThread.java:32`

The line of code that make this exception in prj.ReadThread.run is

```
ObjectInputStream o = new ObjectInputStream(RS.getInputStream());
```

If more information is needed please tell me.

Comment: Show us your code, and the full stack trace of the exception. I really don't see how you could get such an exception when reading from a Vector.

Comment: Nothing in a Vector can throw that exception. The problem is not where you think it is.

Comment: yes, I think that because of using this vector by multiple threads I missed my data some where.(Of course each thread has a different socket for itself)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Wasn't the stacktrace helpful?

The exception appears to be thrown in [`readStreamHeader()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/ObjectInputStream.html#readStreamHeader%28%29), which you can step through in  your debugger. I suspect a [*version number*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_class_file) mismatch. Many classes include a *Warning: Serialized objects of this class will not be compatible with future Xxx releases.*

Addendum: @S Kh helpfully reports the following:

> The problem was because of streams in Java. I was sending packets from a unique stream on the server (an `ObjectOutputStream`), but I received data from a different stream each time on the client via `new ObjectInputStream` for each packet. So that I got this exception.

Comment: Would you please tell me more about version number ?

Comment: Not in less than a book chapter; the _class version_ and _serial version UIDs_ have to match;  see Bloch, _Effective Java_, Chapter 11, Item 74. Edit: What does the debugger show you?

Comment: Leave a comment here if you update your question with new details.

Comment: Of course my problem solved and I want to tell others the answer, maybe some day it would help. 
The problem was because of streams in java. On the other hand I was sending packet by a unique stream in the server( An objectoutputstream ), but receive data from different streams each time in the client(New ObjectInputStream for each packet). So that I got this exception.

Answer (score 1):

Vectors by default are sychronised. If you are sharing them between threads, check that the synchronization policies they implement actually are sufficient to make your program threadsafe (because the existence of some synchronization is little indication of the all-round concurrent behaviour of a class)

Comment: Maybe I asked my question wrong, sorry about that. You are right. But the problem that I got this Exception is that I am using sockets in my program and the main problem is when I want to read an object using GetInputStream() of a socket, it throws this exception.

Comment: So, you get an exception of which we know nothing about except its name, in some Java code we know nothing about except it's using sockets, and you would like us to tell you why you get this exception? The only thing we can tell you is that you get this exception because the stream is corrupted.

Comment: My code have a lot of class so I can't post all of them here. But wasn't the stacktrace helpful ?